# JavaScript image local path

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Sorry for the noob question but i wanted to load a gif on a web page and using the

HTTP link like below it works perfect.

But when i replace it with path it dose not work

The gif is in the same folder of the web page

I did try with:

- /thegifname.gif
- ./thegifname.gif
- //thegifname.gif
- thegifname.gif

but noone of those works, using the debugger in i.e. and breakpoint in the code and local path

./thegifname.gif it works! but without debug tool i can't see the gif.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var size = 0;
var id= 0;

function add_gif() {
    document.getElementById("Label1").style.display = "none";       
    show_image("http://i789.photobucket.com/albums/yy180/Lendisson/progress_bar.gif", 300,15, "Running");
}


function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = src;
    img.width = width;
    img.height = height;
    img.alt = alt;
    document.getElementById("divUpload").style.display="inline";
    var div = document.getElementById("divUpload");
    div.appendChild(img);
 }

 </script>
```

Comment: Are you sure the image exist in the same folder as the page on which you run the js code above?

Comment: Is `#divUpload` inside of `#Label1`? If so, you need to set `display=''` for `#Label1` too.

Comment: hmm ! to confirm, open your firebug and try to click on image src, if it opens image it means it is getting resource right and having some display problem. If not then there is something wrong in path

Comment: and the #divUpload and #label1 are in different par of the page for two differet things

Comment: What exactly means "`it dose not work`", you can't see the image at all or there's only non-loaded image logo? Any errors in the console?

Comment: i MUST use internet explorer , im  forced because the site is a shit (old project) however , i try with deveopler tool of i.e. wait

Comment: @Teemu dose not load the imge so i can't see the gif

Comment: @frank, but as told, from firebug you can see image by clicking, that means image is loaded, just there are some styling issues.

Comment: OMG WITH THE DEBUG I SEE THE IMAGE -.- why ?

Comment: @Saurabh Bayani but with the http i see it, with the debug now i see it , but without debug i can't see nothing  , why?

Comment: debug and local path i ment

Comment: @Saurabh Bayani debug and local path the image load! without debug no!

Comment: @frank, Complete debug process and i am sure you will not see the image, because image is getting loaded properly, but removed lateron by some overriding

Comment: yes you are right man, just post your answer so i give you the points ;)

Comment: those problems comes when it is a mess of files damn.

Comment: @Saurabh Bayani post the answer , i give you points..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK here is procedure to find-out and debug.

`1.` Open your firebug and try to click on image src, if it opens image it means it is getting right image resource and having some display problem.

If not then there is something wrong in path provided check it.

`2.` If image opened properly it means your image loaded properly just got overridden by some other element later-on.

`3.` If that is the case open firebug again and just play with styling properties, you will see your image.

`4.` If not then debug it. you will surely find the problem.

if i left something that you have discovered while recovering from your problem. pls put a comment